# NULL literal in Protege

Tags: owl, ontology, protege

I implementing my ontology model on Protege. I have a class `Sensor` which has some subclasses e.g. subclass `Refrigerator`. If a `Refrigerator-144` is activated I want to save the activation time. I have a data property `hasTime` for this. Because, I do not know the activation time I want to be NULL. But, It seems that it is not acceptable by Protege because I cannot run the Reasoner after this.

```
:Refrigerator-144 a owl:NamedIndividual , :Refrigerator ;
:hasTime ""^^xsd:dateTime .
```

Comment: What means "cannot run the reasoner"? How to you try to run the reasoner? And which reasoner?

Comment: I used FaCT++ and  HermiT when I have NULL literal if I click on reasoner it will not run. I have Protege 5 on mac

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OWL does not have NULL values. A missing value for a property means that there is no assertion with that property for that individual. Creating a literal of type `xsd:dateTime` with a value of `""` will result in an unparsable assertion, which Protege should stop you from entering.

Reasoners should not be affected because the invalid assertion should not have been created.

However, if the triple as you show it is added to the ontology, a reasoner would be correct in rejecting it as an invalid ontology. The empty string does not belong to the value space for `xsd:dateTime`.

Comment: I'm wondering why Protege doesn't reject the literal given that OWL API is used. Does OWL API parse each OWLLiteral w.r.t. to the lexical space of the datatype?

Comment: No, it only attempts to parse the literal forms for integers, doubles and the like - in order to use datatype specific representations and save memory. Invalid literals can be created (without that ability, some of the reasoner conformance tests would not be runnable - although that feels more like a solution looking for a problem than a feature)

Comment: Yes, from my point of view this is more a source of error than a feature. You know, one of the goals in research is to improve the quality of data. Thus, one would expect to let lower-level APIs like OWL API avoid as many errors as possible. Wouldn't it be better to use some separate implementation for those reasoner conformance tests?

Comment: Two problems: we're not in charge of all reasoners, so moving them to another api is not easy; and legacy data. Even in research, data does not get cleaned up easily. Then there are 'idioms', where some researchers use a quirk of a syntax, or even incorrect syntax, to carry information, and have enough users that a bad practice becomes de facto standard. One big can of worms, that is.

Comment: I read [PROV-O document](http://example.com), so If we do not know the value we will update it later right?